# JavaScript : Print some Extra Character

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I Create a Generator Function.

```
function* ask() {
    const name = yield "What is your Name.?";
    const sport = yield "What is your favorite sports.?";
    return `${name}'s favorite sport is ${sport}`;
}

const it = ask();
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next("Ng Sharma"));
console.log(it.next("Cricket"));
```

### Output

When this code run in Node.js.

```
{ value: 'What is your Name.?', done: false }
{ value: 'What is your favorite sports.?', done: false }
{ value: 'Ng Sharma\'s favorite sport is Cricket', done: true }
```

when this code run in Google chorme.

```
{value: "What is your Name.?", done: false}
{value: "What is your favorite sports.?", done: false}
{value: "Ng Sharma's favorite sport is Cricket", done: true}
```

Why do I have these extra this '\' slash, and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I have these extra this '\' slash, and how do I get rid of them?

Since you're outputting the full result object, you're getting Node's default object representation, which uses single quotes around strings. Since it's using single quotes around strings, single quotes (apostrophes) **in** the string are escaped with a backslash to indicate that they aren't the end of the string (just like you do when you write a string in single quotes). The backslash isn't actually in the string. Chrome uses double quotes, not single quotes, around the string values, so there's no need for it to escape the `'`.

If you just output the `value`, it will print the string contents, rather than printing out the full result object from the generator:

```
function* ask() {
    const name = yield "What is your Name.?";
    const sport = yield "What is your favorite sports.?";
    return `${name}'s favorite sport is ${sport}`;
}

const it = ask();
console.log(it.next().value);
console.log(it.next("Ng Sharma").value);
console.log(it.next("Cricket").value);
```

Output:

```
What is your Name.?
What is your favorite sports.?
Ng Sharma's favorite sport is Cricket
```

Comment: Why remove the last line...?

Comment: @NgSharma - Because I realized that my expectation that Node.js would use double quotes in object output was irrelevant to answering the question, and it isn't new behavior (I checked Node v7, v8, and v10, all use single quotes). :-) Whereas before I checked, I thought A) You had an unusual setup, and then B) (After seeing Node v10 did it for me too) That it was a recent change. Apparently neither of those is true. :-) Your setup is normal, I just didn't know this about Node.js (surprisingly, given how much I use it).

Comment: I understand, but same code run in google chrome / (slash) did not show...?

Comment: @NgSharma - Because Chrome uses double quotes, not single quotes, around the string values. (I've added that to the answer.)

Comment: Thank you so much @T.J Crowder